# Google Sheets - Link to Left cell of "MAXIFS" result

Tags: formulas, google-sheets

I have table of heroes with win rates. Now I want to do mini table with best builds for each hero.
[image]

First column is pretty easy with `=UNIQUE(B2:B)`
[image]

In second colunm I use `=MAXIFS(E:E,B:B,J2)` that looks for name from left column `J2(Slate)` in example and search for this name at B column and best win rate in E column:
[image]

Now is the question: In 3 column I want parsed data from C,D and F columns from MAXIFS cell result [Look at hardcoded red letters]. So in L2 it should somehow search for J2(Slate) in B column, then search for K2(70) in E column - result is E2. Now I need to grab data from cells C2,D2 and F2 and merge them to L2. In our example correct value will be "2-5".

Comment: Glory to Ukraine! May be simple `=INDEX($C$2:$C & "-" & $D$2:$D,MATCH(J2&K2,$B$2:$B & $E$2:$E,0))`?

Comment: I suggest that you share a link to your sample spreadsheet shown in your post (or to a copy of it). Otherwise, you are expecting the volunteer contributors to start their own spreadsheet and type in all of your data before even beginning to think about the solution. Help us to help you and share a link.

Comment: @JohnSUN Glory to Heroes! Added also F column: `=INDEX($C$2:$C & "-" & $D$2:$D & $F$2:$F,MATCH(J2&K2,$B$2:$B & $E$2:$E,0))` If you want karma points then add as answer at bottom  =)

Comment: @Erik Tyler Yeah, good idea! Next time I`ll make shared copy.

Comment: @JohnSUN Why did you used strict `$` in formula? Tried without them - result is same.

Comment: @SergeySenkov Yes, you are right, this formula will work correctly for column L, where it should be placed. I indicated a strict binding of the ranges in case, for some reason, the cell with the formula goes to the right or left. And no, I'm not chasing karma, I'm helping people not for the sake of competing with someone. Therefore, you can independently issue the correct answer, I will gladly vote for it.

Comment: OK, Sergey. If you decide to share a link to a spreadsheet copy *this time*, I will take another look. I can tell you at a glance that all results you are looking for can be generated with a single formula instead of many; but it is not an efficient use of time to try to write that formula without readily available data to write around or test it against.